# Prove that $\frac{n^7}{7} +\frac{n^5}{5} + \frac{n^3}{3}+\frac{n^2}{2} -\frac{37n}{210}$ is a positive integer for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction, binomial-theorem

I was solving some questions on  Mathematical induction, when I stumbled upon this problem. I did it in the following manner:

Let $P(n)=$" $\frac{n^7}{7}+\frac{n^5}{5}+\frac{n^3}{3}+\frac{n^2}{2}-\frac{37n}{210}$ is a positive integer"

**Base case:** $(n=1)$ stands true.
⇒ $\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{37(1)}{210}=\frac{247-37}{210}=1$

**Assuming the $P(n)$ is true for $(n=k)$, where $k\in\mathbb{N}$**

⇒$\frac{k^7}{7}+\frac{k^5}{5}+\frac{k^3}{3}+\frac{k^2}{2}-\frac{37k}{210}$ is a positive integer

**But for the Case $(n=k+1)$:**

⇒$\frac{(k+1)^7}{7}+\frac{(k+1)^5}{5}+\frac{(k+1)^3}{3}+\frac{(k+1)^2}{2}-\frac{37(k+1)}{210}$

I am encountering binomial expansions which is making this problem a bit tedious to solve

Please suggest some ways to do this proof more easily and elegantly

Comment: This site uses [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) which is quite similar to LaTex and you need to enclose math in curly braces ```{}```.

Comment: Thanks !! DS for editing the post

Comment: Hint: $\frac17+\frac15+\frac13+\frac12 - \frac{37}{210} = 1$ plus [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem)

Comment: Maybe you could try to show separately that $A_n := 30n^7 + 42 n^5 + 70n^3 + 105n^2 - 37n$ (this is just your expression multiplied by $210$) is positive and that it is divisible by $2$, $3$, $5$ and $7$? Since they are prime, $A_n$ will be divisible by $2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 = 210$ and positive, which is what is desired.

Comment: If $a \mod p = b$ and $a,p \in \Bbb N$, then $\frac ap = k+\frac bp$ for some $k \in \Bbb N_0$. Use this along with Fermat's little theorem.

Comment: @Bruno B I had to use Induction for this question and i already assumed that $A_n$ is a positive integer. But can't prove for $A_(n+1)$

Comment: "I had to use Induction for this question":$\color{red}{\text{why ?}}$

Comment: You can also use the [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) if you really want it to be an elegant _induction_, although my previous comment provides an elegant _solution_.

Comment: Even if you do need to use induction, you could still do separate inductions.

Comment: Ah can you elaborate?@Bruno B

Comment: I did try binomial but it was very tedious and not at all elegant @D S

Comment: well, then you can use my first comment in the induction, but it will just be achille hui's solution in disguise.

Comment: for $n=11$, the quantity in question (5.1M) is a bit over 3/4 times the number of arrangements of a 2x2x2 Rubik's cube

Comment: If 
$$
F(n)=\frac{n^7}{7} +\frac{n^5}{5} + \frac{n^3}{3}+\frac{n^2}{2} -\frac{37n}{210}
$$
then $F(11)=2,816,594$ and $F(101)=15,318,321,684,431$

Answer (score 4):

Just [notice](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28%5Cfrac%7Bm%5E7%7D%7B7%7D+%2B%5Cfrac%7Bm%5E5%7D%7B5%7D+%2B+%5Cfrac%7Bm%5E3%7D%7B3%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7Bm%5E2%7D%7B2%7D+-%5Cfrac%7B37m%7D%7B210%7D%29-%28%5Cfrac%7Bn%5E7%7D%7B7%7D+%2B%5Cfrac%7Bn%5E5%7D%7B5%7D+%2B+%5Cfrac%7Bn%5E3%7D%7B3%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7Bn%5E2%7D%7B2%7D+-%5Cfrac%7B37n%7D%7B210%7D%29++for+m%3Dn%2B1) that
$$
f(n+1)-f(n)=n^6 + 3 n^5 + 6 n^4 + 7 n^3 + 6 n^2 + 4 n + 1,
\quad
f(0)=0
$$

Alternatively, you can replace algebraic manipulations with simple computation, as follows.

[Newton's interpolation formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_series#Newton.27s_series) implies that if a polynomial $f$ of degree $d$ and with rational coefficients takes integer values for $d+1$ consecutive integers, then it takes integers values for all integer arguments because all repeated differences are integers and so are the coefficients in Newton's interpolation formula. Indeed, in this case
$$
f(n) = d_0 \binom{n}{0} + d_1 \binom{n}{1} + d_2 \binom{n}{2} +  d_3 \binom{n}{3} +\cdots
$$
where $d_i$ are the numbers in the first column of the repeated differences array.

For the polynomial in question, we [get](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Table%5B%5Cfrac%7Bn%5E7%7D%7B7%7D+%2B%5Cfrac%7Bn%5E5%7D%7B5%7D+%2B+%5Cfrac%7Bn%5E3%7D%7B3%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7Bn%5E2%7D%7B2%7D+-%5Cfrac%7B37n%7D%7B210%7D%2C%7Bn%2C0%2C7%7D%5D)
$$
\begin{array}{llllllll}
n & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
f(n) & 0 & 1 & 29 & 374 & 2574 & 11839 & 41635 & 121148 \\
\end{array}
$$
and we're done.

Comment: Adapted from https://math.stackexchange.com/a/864247/589

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs (& PSQs), cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Answer (score 1):

May be easier to work backwards.  Start with some instances of Fermat's Little Theorem, for prime $a, b, c, \dots$ and $t = abc \dots$

$$n^a \equiv n \pmod a$$
$$n^b \equiv n \pmod b$$
$$n^c \equiv n \pmod c$$
$$\vdots$$
Apply chinese remainder technique:
$$\frac ta n^a \equiv \frac ta n \pmod t$$
$$\frac tb n^b \equiv \frac tb n \pmod t$$
$$\frac tc n^c \equiv \frac tc n \pmod t$$
$$\vdots$$
Add together:
$$\frac ta n^a  + \frac tb n^b  + \frac tc n^c + \dots \equiv n\left(\frac ta + \frac tb + \frac tc + \dots \right) \pmod t$$
$$\frac {n^a}a  + \frac {n^b}b  + \frac {n^c}c + \dots - n\left(\frac 1a + \frac 1b + \frac 1c + \dots \right) \in \mathbb Z$$
Which is the same as the original problem but with an extra (integer) $n$ subtracted from the left.